# I want the first 5 IDS to printed in a new column which is present between the range (0-1) and corresponding ids present between them

Tags: r, machine-learning, frequency-analysis

I expect the out like this

```
Range    Frequency  IDs 
10-100  4345         id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
100-110 3455         id7 id8 1d9 id10 id11
```

Only five IDs have to be displayed in the column. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do here ? How are you getting id1 to 5 in first row and id7 to id11 in second row? IS this your complete dataset, what other columns do you have?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. As it is currently written, it is unclear what you are asking for. Thank you.